# how to add dynamic values using .each in jquery?

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui

enter image description hereDynamic  value as input:
2 //line 1

8 //line 2

code:
    var a = 0;

```
$('.finealert').each(function (){

   var fine = $(this).html();

   a+ = parseInt(fine);

});
```

Got the output as

```
2               
10
```

Expected output

```
10
```

here two input values i got it dynamically,suppose if you are creating a page for library,we need to generate fine concept those who submit books after their due date and fine amount will generate dynamically,here in each loop first it displays value 2 and during 2nd iteration it displays 10(2+8) but here i want is instead of displaying 2,i want 10(total amount) should replace 2(first value) at the end of all iterations and i want to print the total amount(10) to the user not "2 and 10"

Comment: operator "+ =" not is correct ..... have a space

Comment: 2 //line 1

8 //line 2

2 and 8, where they are?, within the page exactly

Answer (score 0):

try change "html" method for "val" or "text" in otherwises, html method return HTML contents of the element matched

```js
var a = 0;

$('.finealert').each(function (i, obj){
  var fine = $(obj).val();
  a += parseInt(fine);
});

alert(a);
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="http://tjcrowder.github.io/simple-snippets-console/snippet.js"></script>
<input type="text" value="8" class="finealert" />
<input type="text" value="2" class="finealert" />
```

Comment: Dynamic  value as input:  
2
8
hi jose this two input values i got it dynamically

Comment: could you show me how you get them (Dynamic value as input: 2 8)

Comment: right now i don't have tat code,will post you tomorrow morning

Comment: Richardo : ur mail id please can't able upload image and text file here